# Android testing, what to test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, android

I'm quite a noob in the world of testing. I've read all the materials related to Android testing:

- Unit test
- Instrumentation test
- JUnit
- Robolectric
- Espresso
- etc.

The thing is that, all the examples provided only cover very simple use cases, such as verifying whether a text is on the screen or verifying whether the calculation of a function produce the correct result.

Let's say I have an app which is closer to a real-world app: An app that has login and fetch list of items by Retrofit and display it on a RecyclerView.  In this case:

- What are the things that experienced programmers will test?
- In case of Retrofit and RecyclerView how do you actually test it? check if json result match the one displayed on the RecyclerView?

Hope some experts in testing will shed some lights on this.

Comment: Your post is a wall of text. - try to edit it to make it more readable. Another thing: your question is a bit too broad, I think, try to make it more specific. Also, your question would be more on-topic on StackOverflow instead of Software Engineering (in my opinion).

Comment: I edited for format,

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Thx.

Comment: @Mael Stack overflow guys suggest to post here instead as it's not a code-specific question.

Answer (score 2):

> what to test?

Finding the answer to that question is exactly a testers job.

A tester has to identify *test cases* for different *test types* (such as e.g. *Unit Tests*, *Module/Application Tests*, *integration tests*, *load test* and *usability test*) Many of them should be *automated* using *testing frameworks*.

---

> examples provided only cover very simple use cases, such as verifying whether a text is on the screen or verifying whether the calculation of a function produce the correct result. But, let's say I have an app which is closer to a real-world app: An app that has login and fetch list of items by Retrofit and display it on a RecyclerView.

Even your "real world application" gets input data and outputs results somehow.  It is your job to adopt the examples to your concrete application.